# Add a line in TXT file . bat

Tags: for-loop

Dears:

I have the following code, to add a line, "NEW" below to every founded "word" on the same txt file.

```
@echo off


SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set inputFile=C:\Users\msomma\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\test.txt
set outputFile=C:\Users\msomma\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\testSOout.txt
set _strInsert=NEW
set _strFind=WORD
set i=0

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN (`FIND /N "%_strFind%" "%inputFile%"`) DO (set _strNum=%%A)
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%inputFile%") DO (
  set /a i = !i! + 1
  ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
  IF [!i!] == [%_strNum%] (
    ECHO %_strInsert%>>"%outputFile%"
   "
  )
)
END
```

but is not working properly, I just only add "NEW" in one position, exactly the position of the last parameter from the firts for /F.

any advice? thanks a lot.

below are the  TEST.TXT and the result (TEXTSOOUT.TXT):

TEST.TXT:
WORD
2
3
1
WORD
1
1
1

RESULT (TEXTSOOUT.TXT):
WORD
2
3
1
WORD
NEW
1
1
1

Comment: I would suggest you re-write this question after turning off your CAPS-LOCK key.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, best regards.